# Android camera intent open front camera instead of back camera

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm facing a weird problem sending an intent to mobile camera to take picture. In my phone, xaomi 8, works well but when I install the application on samsung a 51 the intent opens front camera instead back camera. The goal is always open back camera on all kind of mobile.
This is my code

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ApplicationConst.CodiceIntentConst.REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE);
}
```

How can I solve it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working for `Samsung A51` and `Pixel 2XL`

```
fun updateIntentForCameraFacing(cameraIntent: Intent, frontFacing: Boolean){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        if(frontFacing)
            cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        else
            cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)

    }
    else if(frontFacing){
        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)

        //samsung
        cameraIntent.putExtra("camerafacing", "front")
        cameraIntent.putExtra("previous_mode", "front")
    }
    else{
        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", false)

        //samsung
        cameraIntent.putExtra("camerafacing", "rear")
        cameraIntent.putExtra("previous_mode", "rear")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code for launching camera intent:

```
MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't so clear in my question :D. I want to open ONLY back camera and not front camera. On my xaomi works well but in samsung a 51 it doesn't because front camera is opened instead of back camera. Thank you

Comment: i understood your point. Can you try above code and pass extra parameter

Comment: With that code, front camera is opened on my xaomi.

Comment: My bad. Updated my answer.

Comment: Also with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE works on my xaomi but front camera on samsung a 51 is opened :(